# Tridion UI 2012 (Experience Manager) - Images Disappear when trying to edit

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, dd4t

I'm implementing Experience Manager / UI 2012 in a Tridion 2011 SP1 DD4T site.

When I click on an Image to edit it, the image selector slides out and I can select a new image. Which exhibits the behaviour described in the comments of this question: [Image component in Experience Manager](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/image-component-in-experience-manager) which unfortunately has no answer. However, when I do not select a new image and click off to another field, the original image disappears. Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

I have double checked the publication target settings and the markup. Just a bit confused as to what is going on.

Comment: I tested it on a 2013 SP1 environment and having the same issue. On different browsers. MarkUp is correct. Seems like it replaces the image tag with the content from Tridion if you click away. And that content isn't a resolved image url, but (probably) a MM link... Unfortunately I have no solution yet... :(

Comment: Did you have a chance to submit this to Support? If working with a client, you may be able to "ask on their behalf" if they haven't done so already.

Comment: Hi Alvin, I haven't yet. I will when I get a chance.

Comment: There is a hotfix for this but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Observing the same behavior under 2013sp1: 1) Clicking on existing image -- selector's rolled out; 2) Clicking outside of any fields -- image disappears, all is left is a generic label: "<add internal link to multimedia content>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What syntax is the image shown in?

If the multimedia component field is wrapped with a  element instead of a  tag, for Tridion 2011 SP1 this is likely addressed in hotfix UI_2012.0.1.88070.

Comment: Elena, here's my case (2013sp1): http://pastebin.com/LgXJDpBj

After clicking outside any field <img/> element vanishes.